# google tag manager api createContainer return 404

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-api-client, google-api-java-client, google-tag-manager-server-side

When I use this api：

getTagManager().accounts().containers().create(accountPath, container).execute();

```
return:

Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
POST https://tagmanager.googleapis.com/tagmanager/v2/accounts/6059691330/containers
{
  "code": 404,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Not found or permission denied.",
      "reason": "notFound"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Not found or permission denied.",
  "status": "NOT_FOUND"
}
```

I tried to search for the answer but failed

Answer (score 0):

The [containers create](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/api/v2/reference/accounts/containers/create) method requires that your application have authorized with the following scope.

[image]

> Not found or permission denied.

Most likely means that either the user you have authorized does not have access or you have not requested the proper scope.